# Delete blank spaces after "$ " in JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to eliminate blank spaces after '$'. E.g:

```
"$  1000" > "$1000"
```

I'm trying to do it like this to eliminate at least one space:

```
text = text.replace(/^($%20)+/, '$');
```

But it's not working, how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
text = text.replace(/\$\s+/, '$');
```

I assume `$` is a regular character. You should rather say what you're trying to achieve.